# Data Extraction using python from Pdf files and export the result

Tags: python

I coded a script for extracting data from pdf files but unfortunately I get the wrong results.

Running the code, it only extracts the data from the first page. So, what do I need to change to extract data from all pages?

Also, I wanna know if it is possible to specify the extracted data like for instance to extract only data which contain a special characters and export them in form of Excel file?

Here is the code.

```
import PyPDF2
import subprocess


def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file: str) -> [str]:
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as pdf:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf, strict=False)
        pdf_text = []
        subprocess.call(['test', 'forms.pdf', 'output'])
        for page in reader.pages:
            content = page.extract_text()
            pdf_text.append(content)

            return pdf_text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    extracted_text = extract_text_from_pdf('test.pdf')
    for text in extracted_text:
        print (text)
```

Comment: Don't put `return` inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

`borb` allows you to extract text using all kinds of filters:

- by text color
- by font
- by location
- by regular expression
- as lines of text
- as paragraphs
- combinations thereof

This is the most basic usecase, extracting all text:

```
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_005.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the text on the first Page
    print(l.get_text()[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The idea here is that we load a PDF, and we attach an `EventListener`. `EventListener` objects are notified whenever the PDF parser hits a particular instruction, for instance "rendering text" or "rendering image", etc.

`SimpleTextExtraction` listens to all rendering events that deal with rendering text. By doing so, it builds an idea of what the text on the page is, and can then be queried.

But there are more advanced examples:

```
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_006.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import RegularExpressionTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    # fmt: off
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[lL]orem .* [dD]olor")
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
    # fmt: on

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print matching groups
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches()[0]):
        print("%d %s" % (i, m.group(0)))
        for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            print(
                "\t%f %f %f %f" % (r.get_x(), r.get_y(), r.get_width(), r.get_height())
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This example , for instance, attempts to match a regular expression. You can then retrieve the bounding box(es) of the match, get the text, etc.

As a last example, I'm going to give you this:

```
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_007.py
import typing
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import LocationFilter
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction


def main():

    # define the Rectangle of interest
    r: Rectangle = Rectangle(Decimal(59), Decimal(740), Decimal(99), Decimal(11))

    # define SimpleTextExtraction
    l0: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()

    # apply a LocationFilter on top of SimpleTextExtraction
    l1: LocationFilter = LocationFilter(r)
    l1.add_listener(l0)

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l1])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the text inside the Rectangle of interest
    print(l0.get_text()[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This example extracts all text that falls inside the bounds of the specified rectangle.

A combination of the previous two examples could already give you the functionality you wanted.

You can use the regular expression example to look for the physical bounds of the special character, you can then modify those bounds (for instance to include the full line, or to include the full paragraph, etc), and then use the code of the last example to retrieve all the text in the (modified) bounds.

You can install `borb` using:

```
pip install borb
```

You can also download its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb).

All of the examples I've used here are also in the [borb examples repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples), which showcases all the things you can do.